# Can you profile a single call of a function with perf?

Tags: c++, linux, profiling, perf

I have a C++ function that I want to profile and only that function. One possible way is to use chrono and just measure the time it takes to run that function and print it out, run the program a few times and then do stats on the samples.

I am wondering if I can skip having to explicitly code time measurements and just ask perf to focus on the time spent in a specified function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Google's benchmarking [library](https://github.com/google/benchmark) to micro-benchmark the function of interest.

You can then profile the resulting the executable as usual using perf.

For example, let's say that following the [basic usage](https://github.com/google/benchmark#basic-usage), you generated an executable named mybenchmark. Then, you can run perf on the binary as usual

```sh
$ perf stat ./mybenchmark
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a [flame graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html) of whole application in SVG format. With flame graph you can quickly see function that take most of the time when consuming CPU. SVG flame graph is interactive: you can click any function and see detailed flame graph only for that selected function. From [description of flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#FlameGraph):

> It is also interactive: mouse over the SVGs to reveal details, and click to zoom.

You can try it in action for sample bash flame graph:

http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpu-bash-flamegraph.svg